# Validation of dates in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to `validate` the following `dates`, which I put in the `database` in `datetime form`. Before them I `check` if the `name` is `empty` and it works, but it won't work with the dates:

```
function validation($data, $files) {
    $errors= array();
    if (empty($data['name'])){
        $errors['name'] = get_string('error:name', 'carhire');
    }
    return $errors;
    //Here the dates won't work:
    if ($data['datefrom'] < $data['dateuntil']) {
        $errors['dateuntil'] = 'ERROR';
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

What I am missing? Thank's for the help.

Comment: Perhaps `if (strtotime($data['datefrom']) < strtotime($data['dateuntil']))`

Comment: Normally, this kind of thing is done with two date pickers, where the second date picker only shows dates later than that picked in the first date picker (and vice versa), so this kind of validation should be unnecessary

Comment: I use two datepickers, but it is impossible to show dates later than in the first date picker (in Moodle).  `strtotime` won't work. Both dates are set as `datetime` in the db.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to read the date. What date is `02/03/04` to you? The second of march 2004 or the 3rd of february 2004? You can be sure that `datetime` will understand it correctly if you input it into your DB as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the function like it is shown above it won't work, because you are ending it before the date can be "validated".

Remove the first `return $errors;`

```
function validation($data, $files) {
            $errors= array();
            if (empty($data['name'])){
                $errors['name'] = get_string('error:name', 'carhire');
            }
            return $errors; // <--- this will exit the function
            //Here the dates won't work:
            if ($data['datefrom'] < $data['dateuntil']) {
                $errors['dateuntil'] = 'ERROR';
            }
            return $errors;
}
```

---

Since this was not the solution I have another input.
(requires php 5.2+)

```
function validation($data, $files) {
            $errors= array();
            if (empty($data['name'])){
                $errors['name'] = get_string('error:name', 'carhire');
            }
            //Here the dates won't work:
            $date_from = new DateTime($data['datefrom']); // example 2016-01-18 08:55:00
            $date_until = new DateTime($data['dateuntil']); // example 2016-01-19 08:55:00
            if ($date_from < $date_until) {
                $errors['dateuntil'] = 'ERROR';
            }
            return $errors;
}
```

I tested it with the values stated in comments and it worked for me (I got the error message).
If it doesn't work, make sure the date values are set correctly in the array.

Comment: The first return was to check if the name check will work. I just forgot to comment it out here. But still, it wont work, it doesn't check the dates. In the db they are in the following format 2016-01-18 08:55:00

Comment: Now shows the following message, even the dates are correct "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1453722000) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character"

Comment: This error comes up when the variable, which is passed to the datetime class, is not a valid date format. One of the dates is a timestamp. Which is stated in the error: 1453722000 So you need to convert one of them.